# Simplifying excel formula

Tags: excel

I am having an issue simplifying this formula for easier use.

```
=IFERROR(
    (        SUM(
            (                COUNTIFS(
                    January!$L$3:$L$251,
                    ">=0",
                    January!$L$3:$L$251,
                    "<0.000695",
                    January!$E$3:$E$251,
                    "=Fire District 1",
                    January!$D$3:$D$251,
                    "=Structural"
                ) ),
            (                COUNTIFS(
                    February!$L$3:$L$251,
                    ">=0",
                    February!$L$3:$L$251,
                    "<0.000695",
                    February!$E$3:$E$251,
                    "=Fire District 1",
                    February!$D$3:$D$251,
                    "=Structural"
                ) ),
            (                COUNTIFS(
                    March!$L$3:$L$251,
                    ">=0",
                    March!$L$3:$L$251,
                    "<0.000695",
                    March!$E$3:$E$251,
                    "=Fire District 1",
                    March!$D$3:$D$251,
                    "=Structural"
                ) ),
            (                COUNTIFS(
                    April!$L$3:$L$251,
                    ">=0",
                    April!$L$3:$L$251,
                    "<0.000695",
                    April!$E$3:$E$251,
                    "=Fire District 1",
                    April!$D$3:$D$251,
                    "=Structural"
                ) ),
            (                COUNTIFS(
                    May!$L$3:$L$251,
                    ">=0",
                    May!$L$3:$L$251,
                    "<0.000695",
                    May!$E$3:$E$251,
                    "=Fire District 1",
                    May!$D$3:$D$251,
                    "=Structural"
                ) ),
            (                COUNTIFS(
                    June!$L$3:$L$251,
                    ">=0",
                    June!$L$3:$L$251,
                    "<0.000695",
                    June!$E$3:$E$251,
                    "=Fire District 1",
                    June!$D$3:$D$251,
                    "=Structural"
                ) ),
            (                COUNTIFS(
                    July!$L$3:$L$251,
                    ">=0",
                    July!$L$3:$L$251,
                    "<0.000695",
                    July!$E$3:$E$251,
                    "=Fire District 1",
                    July!$D$3:$D$251,
                    "=Structural"
                ) ),
            (                COUNTIFS(
                    August!$L$3:$L$251,
                    ">=0",
                    August!$L$3:$L$251,
                    "<0.000695",
                    August!$E$3:$E$251,
                    "=Fire District 1",
                    August!$D$3:$D$251,
                    "=Structural"
                ) ),
            (                COUNTIFS(
                    September!$L$3:$L$251,
                    ">=0",
                    September!$L$3:$L$251,
                    "<0.000695",
                    September!$E$3:$E$251,
                    "=Fire District 1",
                    September!$D$3:$D$251,
                    "=Structural"
                ) ),
            (                COUNTIFS(
                    October!$L$3:$L$251,
                    ">=0",
                    October!$L$3:$L$251,
                    "<0.000695",
                    October!$E$3:$E$251,
                    "=Fire District 1",
                    October!$D$3:$D$251,
                    "=Structural"
                ) ),
            (                COUNTIFS(
                    November!$L$3:$L$251,
                    ">=0",
                    November!$L$3:$L$251,
                    "<0.000695",
                    November!$E$3:$E$251,
                    "=Fire District 1",
                    November!$D$3:$D$251,
                    "=Structural"
                ) ),
            (                COUNTIFS(
                    December!$L$3:$L$251,
                    ">=0",
                    December!$L$3:$L$251,
                    "<0.000695",
                    December!$E$3:$E$251,
                    "=Fire District 1",
                    December!$D$3:$D$251,
                    "=Structural"
                ) )
        ) / C21 ),
    "N/A"
)
```

What I am trying to do is pull info from worksheets made for each month and counting them if they meet the specific requirements.  Then I divide them by the total for the year to get a percentage of these that met all requirements.  I added the `iferror` in case there are no events, so instead of getting the div/0 error ill get N/A.  This way I set up a conditional format to black out the cell if it shows N/A.  Problem is I have to do this for 200 more cells, so I would like to simplify the formula and I know its possible but don't have the expertise to do so. Thank you for any help!!!

---

That is my fault I should have put more background on the information being pulled.  I work for a fire department and each worksheet is a months worth of data collected on times, locations, and dates for emergencies.  We have a time we have to meet for each portion of the emergencies and we have to meet that time 90% of the time.  My base formula:

```
=COUNTIF(
    January!$L$3:$L$251,
    ">=0",
    January!$L$3:$L$251,
    "<0.00695",
    January!$E$3:$E$251,
    "=Fire District 1",
    January!$D$3:$D$251,
    "=Structural")
```

This counts the emergency if in column L is >=0 but <= 1 minute.  Column E is where the data is for what fire district the emergency occurred in and column D is the type of emergency it is. In this case i want it to count the emergency if it is  Structural emergency located in District 1 and they met their time of dispatching the emergency in 1 min.  I then have a table set up to count the different types of emergencies for each district (5 in total).  So I take all the runs that met those requirements and divide them by the total I have that is calculated in a different table.  Each step is required because we need all the individual data. All the data being pulled is in the same exact location just spread across 12 worksheets, but I am self taught and can't figure out how pull all the worksheets at once if that is possible instead of repeating the formula 12 times to count the emergencies for each worksheet.  I am very sorry if I cause any confusion with my lack of background and terrible programming.  The program works but I can tell it is quite amateurish and extremely messy, sorry again.

Comment: Nex time use http://excelformulabeautifier.com/ to make your formulas readable...

Answer (score 0):

First things first - that is an incredibly messy formula.

In this case, I think the best way to do your formula is to create a table. In the column on the left, have the months (call it in column B). In the headers, have the Fire Districts (call it in row 3), and in a free form field, have the type (such as structural, call it in cell A1).

Once you have that set up, a formula that counts all three criteria would be simpler and much easier to implement. You will need COUNTIFS and INDIRECT.

The suggested formula could be:

```
=iferror(countifs(INDIRECT(B3&"!$L$3:$L$251"),"<0.000695",INDIRECT(B3&"!$E$3:$E$251"),"="&C3,INDIRECT(B3&"!$D$3:$D$251"),"="&A1)/C21),"")
```

If you have the names of the months in column B, this formula will redirect the COUNTIFS function to change spreadsheet every time you change the row.

As a note, you might consider changing any zeros in the various month spreadsheets to " ", as this will stop the formula from picking them up.

Comment: In response to the additional information below, I suggest that instead of reinventing the wheel for each stage, you tabulate as much of the information as possible, and then draw further data from there. You seem to need to need to calculate the amount of call outs in given districts that meet the call out times and then as a percentage of the total cask outs in that district. If that is the case, I would tabulate them all, calculate the totals, and work from there.